# erase a damaged iphone

Tags: iphone

My son has an iPhone 11 that got severely smashed on the front and back so badly that you can't see anything but light on the screen, can't power down with the power button, and we can't get the icloud Erase function to work without it connecting to Wi-Fi. If it is erasing we can't tell. Therefore we can't use our Carrier's insurance plan to replace the phone because if we send it in and it's not erased it will cost hundreds more.  Any suggestions on how to erase it using a computer when you can't see the phone screen?

Comment: Are there any WiFi networks which the phone will have remembered and already logged into?  A very few retailers have networks that don't require an interstitial screen, one is Target.  You could also try using "Find my iPhone" and using the remote wipe procedure, which designed for when a hostile party has taken your phone.  Also call the insurance and ask if it applies to phones that are too smashed to erase... both cell and wifi antennas may be broken.

Comment: Did you try connecting it to a computer? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252

Comment: Have you asked them how to deal with this issue? I suspect the fee may be for iCloud Activation Lock specifically, which you can disable by removing it from Find My iPhone: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201441 If this is removed then they shouldn't charge a fee